# Не создает json и csv файл

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, request

Программа не выдает никаких ошибок, но тем не менее ничего не выводит в консоль и не создает нужные файлы при парсинге, в чем может быть проблема?

```html
import csv
import json
import os.path
import os
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime


def get_all_pages():

    headers = {
        'user-agent' :'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'
        }
    
r = requests.get(url='https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?page=1&producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer')
if not os.path.exists("data"):
        os.mkdir("data")

with open("data/page_1.html", "w") as file:
        file.write(r.text)
with open("data/page_1.html") as file:
        src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")

pages_count = 20
for i in range(1,pages_count + 1):

    url = f'https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?page={i}&producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer'

    r = requests.get(url  = url)

    with open(f'data/page_{i}.html','w') as file:
        file.write(r.text)
        time.sleep (2)
        

def collect_data(pages_count):
     with open(f"parcerRozetka_{cur_date}.csv", "w") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)

        writer.writerow(
            (
                "Дата",
                "Артикул",
                "Цена",
                'Наличие'
            )
        )
data = []
cur_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")

for page in range (1, pages_count):
  
             with open (f'data/page_{page}.html') as file: src = file.read()

             soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')

             items_card = soup.find_all('div', class_='goods-tile__inner')

             for item_card in soup.find_all('li', class_='catalog-grid__cell catalog-grid__cell_type_slim ng-star-inserted'):

                 product_article = item.find('span', class_='goods-tile__title').text

                 product_price = item.find('p', class_='ng-star-inserted').text.strip()

                 product_nal = item.find('div', class_='goods-tile__availability goods-tile__availability--available ng-star-inserted').text

                 data.append ({

                     "Data": cur_date,

                     "product_article": product_article,
                    
                    "product_price": product_price,

                    "product_nal": product_nal
                     })
                 with open(f"parcerRozetka_{cur_date}.csv", "a") as file:

                     writer = csv.writer(file)

                     writer.writerow ((
                         
                         cur_date,
                         product_article,
                         product_price,
                         product_nal
                         ))

                 print (f'[info] Обработана страница {page}/20')

                 with open(f'parcerRozetka{cur_date}.json', 'a') as file:
                     json.dump(data, file, indent = 3, ensure_ascii = False)

def main():
               get_all_pages()
               collect_data(pages_count=pages_count)
               if __name__ == '__main__':

                   main()
```

Comment: Мне кажется, там нужен Selenium, содержимое страниц там не такое уж простое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
               get_all_pages()
               collect_data(pages_count=pages_count)
               if __name__ == '__main__':

                   main()
```

А ничего, что вызов функции упрятан в середину самой функции.
Понятно, что программа ничего не делает, так как вы ее нигде не вызываете. Может все-таки глянете в учебник, где написано и как программу вызывать на исполнение, и что делает конструкция `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Это была небольшая опечатка, но тем не менее она ни на что не повлияла и данные все так же не выводит (Розетка в другом коде на bs4 парсила без проблем)

Comment: Это, конечно, ошибка, но проблема не в этом, я проверял )

Comment: Хорошо, пытался обойтись без него, но видимо прийдется, спасибо вам!